# What is the SI unit of magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetic, emf, field

As derived from F = qvB sinθ, what is the unit of magnetic force, and why?

Edit: I mistakenly asked about magnetic field before. -- I'm asking the magnetic force.

Comment: You don't want to memorize, "but [instead to] understand the logic behind it." The answers you've been given don't provide a deeper understanding. (Ask yourself why it is that there might be no magnetic field in one frame of reference, while there is a magnetic field in another. Look into Lagrange's equations of motion, Hamiltonian mechanics, and gauge invariance. Finally, symmetry arguments and reflection space may provide some intuition.) This is probably the wrong place for the *logic behind*. You might try the physics stackexchange. See if they can help.

Comment: @ jonk "reflection space" ?? I don't recall that phrase in the book you recommended.

Comment: In some reference frames, there is a time difference between various points, resulting in different (orthogonal) forces. We call these (slight, orthogonal) forces the magnetic field. To pretend to understand this in a simple manner, math methods conjure up the magnetic field. TRUE? Note I'm using two words here: forces and fields, as different.

Answer (score 2):

It's a force, and that's always measured in Newtons.

B is not A/m, H is measured in A/m. B is measured in \$kg.s^{-2}.A^{-1}\$, base units, or the rather more electrically appropriate volt.seconds per m2, or Webers/m2.

We use sine or cosine depending on what we take to be the reference direction, whether it's along or normal to the conductor. The only difference is 90 degrees.

Comment: Then why are we treating B as H in Lorenz law?

Comment: Ask yourself about the units of \$\mu\$, the ratio of B and H, and how the example you're quoting is using it.

Answer (score 2):

> while I also don't understand why we use sine but not cosine

Because the actual formula is \$\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}\$ and the vector cross product is defined so that the magnitidue of the cross product is 0 if the two vectors are parallel, and maximized when the two vectors are orthogonal.

> What is the SI unit of magnetic field?

The units are tesla (T).

$$ 1\ {\rm T} = 1 \frac{\rm N \cdot s}{\rm C \cdot m},$$

or, in SI base units

$$ 1\ {\rm T} = 1 \frac{\rm kg}{\rm A \cdot s^2}.$$

Comment: But if cross-product gives us already the perpendicular vector, then why do we multiply it again with sine ?

Comment: The formula you gave is for the magnitude of the force. It isn't a vector equation. To get the magnitude of a cross product, you need to include the sine of the angle between the vectors, \$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\sin\theta\$.

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind that.

Comment: Because we find that this math accurately predicts the forces acting on moving particles subject to magnetic effects. (Note: The field itself is also just a mathematical convenience. The way we define the B field produced by a current or magnetic dipole is also part of "the math" that we need to define to make our predictive model)

Comment: I think I kind of understood. So, it is not something that we conclude logically, but it is because how it (magnitude) can be represented/calculated accurately mathematicaly? I thought the princible was the same as with electrical flux, where E and F are in the same direction, and to find electric field / given area, we multiply E.A.cos (to find the parallel lines and multiply them). I think I need to go over scalar and vectoral multiplications, and I just don't want to memorize, but understand the logic behind it.

Comment: The cross product lets us calculate both magnitude and direction of the force. The force caused by the B field is not in the same direction as the B vector.

Comment: For example, if two parallel wires carry current in the same direction, the force on wire 2 is directly toward wire 1. Measuring this force is actually how the ampere is  defined (although this is changing in May 2019).

Comment: @ Vyun If I recall rightly, the Magnetic Field is orthogonal to the Magnetic Force, just because that makes the math work out. DId I phrase that rightly, @ Photon???

Comment: Why is a cross product gives another vector which is perpendicular to the parallelogram? How can the direction of magnetic force (field and velocity as well) be determined, so that this equation/solution arises? What does force being up or down affect on the electric charges' movements? And I still couldn'T grasph why the force is in Newton. (how to differentiate magnetic flux from magnetic field?)

Comment: @Vyun, the SI unit of force is the newton. It doesn't matter if the force is produced by magentism, static electricity, gravity, or a steam engine. You're free to measure it in dynes or pounds if you like, but that will just force anybody you talk to to have to convert to newtons to compare your numbers with somebody else's.

Comment: If you want to know about the units for measuring the magnetic field, that's not a force, it's a magnetic field. If you want to know about the units for that, you should ask a separate question.

Comment: No, I am asking about the force.

Comment: "What does force being up or down affect on the electric charges' movements?" --- If you apply a downward force on an object it will accelerate downwards. If you apply an upward force on an object, it will accelerate upwards. This is simple mechanics. If you want to ask about this, you should ask on physics.stackexchange.com, not electronics.

Comment: "Why is a cross product gives another vector which is perpendicular to the parallelogram?" --- This is simply how the cross product is defined. This is a question for mathematics.stackexchange.com, not electronics or even physics.

Comment: But, doesn't a vector shows also the direction, thus, doesn't it mean the force is applied upward or downward on the charge? The reason why I am not asking this on physics or math is because I do not know why two variables horizontal (Bxv) would create a force perpendicular to these.

Comment: Yes, force is a vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87409/discussion-between-the-photon-and-vyun).

Answer (score 2):

In SI units, B is measured in teslas (symbol: T) and correspondingly ΦB (magnetic flux) is measured in webers (symbol: Wb) so that a flux density of 1 Wb/m2 is 1 tesla. The SI unit of tesla is equivalent to (newton. second)/(coulomb. metre). - Wikipedia